# Hide running batch script with admin rights by use .vbs in second getCmdPID.bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

I want to hide the admin.bat console window when it executes commands from ADMINTASKS line. Is it possible to give pid in vbscript or another way to hide console?

**run.vbs**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c admin.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

**admin.bat**

```
@echo off
title=mycmd
echo test
NET SESSION
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ELEVATE
GOTO ADMINTASKS

:ELEVATE
CD /d %~dp0
MSHTA "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 1);close();"
EXIT

:ADMINTASKS
::(Do whatever you need to do here)
pause
EXIT
```

**getCmdPID.bat**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
  'tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "mycmd"'
) do (
  set "mypid=%%~a"
)
echo %mypid%
::here should be modifications
start admin.bat
pause
```

Comment: So you only want to hide only those parts of the script, or the entire batch?

Comment: the entire batch

Comment: then just call `admin.bat` from `getCmDPID.bat` and call `getCmDPID.bat` from you hideme `vbs` script. the vbs will hide all from thereon. If you are not sure what I am trying to say, I will post an answer with the relevant flow.

Comment: the answer would be helpful, because I can not modify getCmdPID.bat and I would like the vbs script to provide the path to the file

Comment: So you cannot modify anything in `getCmdPID.bat`?

Comment: I'm not advanced in writing scripts

Comment: let me post an answer.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 1)` with `shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 0)`?. Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shell-shellexecute) it should work.

Comment: `shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 0)` it executes a white window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have 2 possible scenarios you want to end up with.

Secario 1. Have both scripts hidden from view, here you would launch `run.vbs` which will hide both scripts:

**run.vbs**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
oShell.Run "D:\getCmdPID.bat", 0, false
```

**admin.bat**

```
@echo off
title=mycmd
echo test
NET SESSION
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ELEVATE
GOTO ADMINTASKS

:ELEVATE
CD /d %~dp0
MSHTA "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 1);close();"
EXIT

:ADMINTASKS
::(Do whatever you need to do here)
pause
EXIT
```

**getCmdPID.bat**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
  'tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "mycmd"'
) do (
  set "mypid=%%~a"
)
echo %mypid%
::here should be modifications
start admin.bat
pause
```

Or, Scenario 2, you want the user to see the `getCmDPID.bat` file, but hide `admin.bat` but here, you would Start the `getCmdPID.bat file, which will call run.vbs and in turn will call`admin.bat in hidden mode.

**run.vbs**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
oShell.Run "D:\admin.bat", 0, false
```

**admin.bat**

```
@echo off
title=mycmd
echo test
NET SESSION
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ELEVATE
GOTO ADMINTASKS

:ELEVATE
CD /d %~dp0
MSHTA "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 1);close();"
EXIT

:ADMINTASKS
::(Do whatever you need to do here)
pause
EXIT
```

**getCmdPID.bat**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
  'tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "mycmd"'
) do (
  set "mypid=%%~a"
)
echo %mypid%
::here should be modifications
"D:\run.vbs"
pause
```

Comment: why I need to run getCmdPID.bat as an administrator?